# Couldn't change background color with css

Tags: css

I wanna change my login page background color but there's no change when I try to change this code

```
body{
    background:#f1f9f9;
}
```

It shows me navy color always. What's wrong about it? I have tried to change all of code color in full style.css file, but still there's no change for all color include. 
This is style.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    background:#f1f9f9;
}

.form-signin {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin h2, .office h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top:18px;
  margin-bottom:45px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,0 3px 0 #bbb,0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,0 5px 0 #aaa,0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15)
}

.form-signin .form-signin-heading{
    color:#00A2D1;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"],
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #f1f9f9;
    padding: 7px 9px;
}

.signin-form
{
  margin-top:110px;
}
.body-container
{
    margin-top:70px;
}
body.special-page{
  background: url("../img/special-page-bg.png") no-repeat scroll top center #2b3237;  
}
.navbar-brand{
    font-family:"Lucida Handwriting";
}
#btn-submit{
    height:45px;
}
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
.footer {
  padding: 40px 0;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This is the login page code (index.php) about css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portal Bimbingan TA Polmed</title>

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shoutcut icon" href="logo.png">
</head>
<body class="special-page"> 
    <div class="signin-form">
        <div class="container">
        ..............
```

Wish your help very much. I don't like to see the navy color because my university default color is purple (I make a university web). It's strange for me to see it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you right click on your page in Chrome, click inspect and take a full screenshot of dev tools and share with us, please? Make sure you have selected the `<body` tag on the left side. Or is there a way for us to have a look at it online? Do you have any link or something?

Comment: use **!important** keyword

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar Purushothaman This is http://www.siteofmeylina.web.id/ Would u help me please? Where to be changed? Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did change body background color but you have this class on your background and you styled it:

```
body.special-page{
    background: url("../img/special-page-bg.png") no-repeat scroll top center #2b3237;  
}
```

try to this :

```
body.special-page{
    background: f1f9f9;  
}
```

Comment: Thakns for ur responses. I'll try it. Thanks a lot.